# JavaScript for-loop... for(i=0;i<10;i--)s=s+i;

Tags: javascript

```
for ( i = 0; i < 10; i-- ) s = s + i;
```

Why does the following loop return an error?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the error?

Comment: Probably "One of the scripts on this page is very slow" or whatever.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's an infinite loop, because you are decrementing `i`, in stead of incrementing `i`. Therefor `i` will always be less then `10` (the condition of the `for` loop).

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
   s=s+i();
}
```

Comment: Switching from JavaScript to a different language to solve the infinite loop problem? Interesting approach... `:P`

Comment: lol oh wait you're right. My bad. I'd love to know if it worked though.